# Removing diagonal blue grid lines with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hi I found [this image](https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lifestyle-set-2/100/62e7c85d5ee356f4a1e17fd0ca344590-512.png). But I don't want to have the blue lines on the image. How do I go about removing those lines with Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is click [this link](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/601670/pomodoro_pomodoro_technique_timer_tomato_icon) and below the icon you will see an option to buy it for $1.50USD, which will give you the icon in various formats without the lines.

Comment: Oh didn't know it costed money. Okay thanks for the heads up

Comment: I can understand wanting to remove the lines, as I have been there in the past, but honestly, it's easier and takes way less time to just buy it, and you can recover that minimal cost really easily.

Comment: The fastest way to accomplish a Graphic Design issue :)

Comment: @hsawires but if you outsource everything what value do you bring?

Comment: @joojaa sure, I was kidding :)

Comment: @Ce. Not to mention it's the most fair way to the creator. Someone put time and effort into creating it, and by removing the lines you're basically stealing the icon from that person. One day you might be in the same position so treat your fellow designers well :)

Comment: @joojaa don't lose the grip! How about "Change the blue color to orange"